# "In Process" session config, in use, on a small Azure website instance, could it be contributing to performance issues?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, azure, azure-web-app-service

Just trying to isolate some performance issues we are getting on our production site.

The current setup is :

Small Standard Website instance(1 core, 1.75gb RAM)
MVC3
ASP.NET 4.5
EF5

32bit setup

I am using an "in process" session setup which I understand may be part of my issue. I get slow ups. I monitor the site with New Relic.

My session code, in web.config is:

```
   <sessionState mode="InProc" timeout="30">
       <providers>
          <add name="DefaultSessionProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultSessionStateProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" />
       </providers>
   </sessionState>
```

I have read that "in Proc" does not work in Azure websites, but it does for me? Whether it works and has issues, I am unsure.

Your advice on the above would be appreciated.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

InProc session management should not be making your site slower, it's the fastest way to manage the session.
The InProc session will work OK as long as you have only 1 instance running your code.
InProc session is mantained in the server's RAM, so as soon as you start using more than 1 instance, and the load balancer decides to take the user to a different instance than the one she logged in, she will have to log in again (on that new server).

Comment: Thanks for this. The "as long as you have only 1 instance" is key, since ,my 1 standard instance is set to autoscale when cpu gets to 80%, which will cause a session issue I suspect. Also I am now worried about sessions and "thread agility issues" which can cause a read/write lock. Good to hear your view on 1 instance, and it backs up my experience, although I now realise it is not a good longer term solution.